# Is it possible to use an Amstrad CPC464 with a modern monitor or TV

Tags: display, cpc, cpc464

During a recent move I lost the monitor for my Amstrad CPC464.

Is it possible to adapt the output of this to work on a modern monitor or on television set?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are a number of ways:

- If your TV has a SCART connector, you need a cable adapter from DIN 6 to SCART, wired like this (the audio is taken from the audio out using a standard stereo 3.5'' jack):

(taken from CPCwiki)

[image]

- If your TV does not have SCART, but composite video input, you must

  - Either use a RGB to CVBS adapter (using for example an AD724 chip), or
  - if you don't mind having a B&W signal, you can make an easier adapter by taking pin 6 (LUMA) to the CVBS input.

For the first solution, we did a small batch of a little PCB that holds an AD724 and associated components to get a cheap RGB to CVBS/S-Video adapter. This is the schematic:

[image]

And this is the board, almost finished:

[image]

- If your TV has an HDMI input, then the solution is to wire a cable adapter as first explained, and then use a SCART-to-HDMI upscaler.

[image]

- For a VGA monitor, use a RGB-to-VGA converter. They are very common and used in custom arcade cabinets.

[image]

I have one of these, and this is how my CPC6128 looks in a TFT monitor :) (it looks darker but that is because of the short exposure of my camera)

[image]